# How to combine multiple png icons into one transparent iconset

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon

What software can I use to combine multiple transparent png and icon files into one transparent iconset?

Example:

[image: example image]

Comment: They can be  placed perfectly with the help of most graphic design software. 

like you can use Photoshop with the help of grids you can align very well manually.

Comment: How to automatically align? Thank.

Comment: there are some software who provide the same it would be best if you google the same

Comment: For website purposes `css sprite generator`'s are great because they give the css code as well as the sprite sheet. http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ This one might have the most options.

Comment: You can use the Align/Distribute tool in Photoshop/Gimp/Illustrator and do it "by hand".
Or if you want to generate a Sprite: http://www.spritecow.com/
If not, please explain what do you need this for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS Sprite generator. There are a few of them out there. You usally just upload all the icons and let the website do the rest.

http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

I make mine by hand. I like having lots of clearly labeled layers so I can find things in the future and maintain the images. Personal preference I suppose.

Comment: +1 for the website suggestion. It's a shame that it only supports zips up to 1Mg

Answer (score 0):

You should easily be able to do that by hand in Photoshop. If you'd like to automate it, I'd see if a Adobe Bridge's Contact Sheet feature gets you what you're after.

Information and video:
[Creating Contact Sheets in Adobe Bridge](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS42C3020A-DAD1-4f92-8014-012263F3A51D.html)

Comment: he said "automatically"

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for windows ico format , you can use this plugin for Photoshop . but it's bit old though.

http://www.sibcode.com/icon-plugin/

Comment: Please try to explain in more detail what the plugin does and if you have tested it. _but it's bit old though_ is a little vague. :)